# Finding the vlc.so file in linux - Java Development

Tags: java

I want to play video in `JFrame` by using VLCJ framework. In windows program is working fine

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"/usr/share/man/man1/vlc.1");
```

The line in Double Quotes ("") is the place where we provide path of the `VLC.so` (`vlc.dll` in windows) can any one tell me where exactly can I get the `vlc.so` file.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The library is `libvlc.so` and part of the packages `libvlc-dev`.

Therefore install the development library via

```
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

The complete path of the library is

```
/usr/lib/libvlc.so
```